# TinyMCE4 - valid_elements property not working for 'em'

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Want to allow certain tags & properties while pasting from Word/WebPage to TinyMCE4 Editor. I tried to set the configuration as below :

> oEvent.getParameters().configuration.valid_elements="em,a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br,p[align]";

Now I am able to paste only paragraph,bold & link not  text with em tag.

Any idea why its not working ?

I want to allow only certains tags like Paragraph,Stong,StrikeThrough,Bullets.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any issue with using that `valid_elements` setting. Please see this TinyMCE fiddle:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Dmgaab

One editor allows `EM` and the other does not  ...  and TinyMCE works as I would expect.

Comment: While pasting I am facing the issue. Instead of Paste, I am using PowePaste plugins. While pasting itself, I want to allow following things only : 
1> Same font size & font colour ( for this I have used Powerpaste plugin )
2> I dont want any attribute while pasting from web
3> Only following formatting should be allowed: Bold,Italics,Hyperlink,Bullet,Numbered list,Strike through,Underline. 

I tried to apply:

valid_elements="span,em,a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br,p[align]";

but it is allowing only paragraph,bold & link .

Comment: PowerPaste is a commercial (paid) plugin ... if you have purchased that product you should open a support case on the Ephox support site.

Comment: We are building application using SAP UI5/Fiori. We have one control which is inheriting TinymCE4. Here is the link :

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.richtexteditor.RichTextEditor/overview

Answer (score 2):

Pasting content from word is quite a complicated problem - you'll likely be able to make some functions carry over nicely on your own / with the free version, but tinymce has an extensive paid plugin to handle pastes if that's what you want.

For now, I would try adding `span` to your list of `valid_elements`. It would depend on your text source, but I know that tinymce handles italics internally through `<span>` elements.

```
valid_elements: "span,em,a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br,p[align]"
```

Comment: Tried but not working :( We are developing application using SAPUI5/Fiori which is using this 3rd Party library. I don't why one is working & other not working :(